# Good design and good user interface ASP.NET Ajax applications?

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I like to get inspiration from using web applications that make good use of new technologies. This time I would like to check out ASP.NET based web applications that make heavy use of Ajax & Ajax Toolkit for line of business apps (data bound controls like grids). I checked out some apps at CodePlex but didn't see anything cool enough.

Any recommendations? Preferably an app with source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your going to find what your looking for easily. The AJAX toolkit lacks the slickness of the plugins of jQuery and other popular frameworks. If you are looking to be impressed, you may want to look elsewhere than the toolkit.

I'm not sure what framework it's build on, but I have been very impressed by the UI of [MailChimp](http://www.mailchimp.com) lately. They nailed it, so easy to use and elegant.